# How to create GeoTagging image / location tagging application for android with google maps using eclipse with ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, tagging, geotagging

Hello my name is James,

I am self-learning how to develop android applications, I have designed few basic apps – to name a few calculator app, notepad, percentage calculator for android. After developing few small basic apps, I am planning on making more advance apps, I am planning on creating an app that allows the user to tag their location on google map or geotag images using the application, which will only be visible to them. For example, the user can tag location to a map and later on get directions to that location or take an image of a location and geotag it to the map and add some sort of description to it.

I have been searching on google for some time now, on how I can go about designing this app but I haven’t really found any tutorial / guides how to implement the image geotagging / location tagging to google map.

Please can someone give me some guide, something to read upon or maybe correct me if am not searching for the right materials.

So far, I have carried out searches including:
How to add google maps to my android application (I found a good guide for this and I understand how I can do this)
How to implement geotagging on your android application (Haven’t found any useful material apart from few applications released on play store)
How to implement location tagging (Haven’t found any useful material for this either)
I found a video on YouTube where the person has designed a similar app that I am planning on doing http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_V49bXXtnvU but other than I have only come across videos / guides that shows how to add google maps to your android application something like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you found your answers already, but in case you or someone else is still looking:
 - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

I found that tutorial helpful in getting started with `MapsActivity`.  If you are using Android Studio then just start a new project with the main activity selected as Map activity.  This will start you off with a lot of the necessary code for starting the Google Maps API.  It will walk you through how to get your google api key for your app.
Once you have that set up, then look at the several listeners that are available for the map.  Some that you may want are `Map.setOnMapLongClickListener`, `Map.setOnMarkerClickListener`, `Map.setOnMarkerDragListener`.  These will help you decide what to do with locations on the map.
Look at the `Marker` class to be used Google Map.  You will set your tags/markers with this class.  You can replace the default marker with your image if you like or create your own custom tag.  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker?hl=en

You can use `LocationManager` to get your current location.  Here is a simple tutorial: http://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/

If you plan on providing Camera within your app or get images from gallery, you should review the Camera Class : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

and a simple tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_camera.htm

I would add one feature at a time when starting your app project.
Create the map with working key and make sure it displays a map.
Then, add a marker on your current location (on an emulator, you will have to set the default location because it will not have gps).
Then, allow the user to add a marker by i.e long pressing on a map location.
Then, open a dialog box of choices when long pressing on map, i.e tag location, tag with custom tag, tag with camera image, etc.